# How to enable Seam 3 debug level logging on a Glassfish server

Tags: jsf, glassfish, seam, cdi, seam3

After migrating to CDI/Seam 3 I'm getting these messages in my server log:

```
WARN: Cannot attempt extension on null.
```

I saw a post in the Seam 3 forum (which is not accepting new posts at present)
with some logging from org.jboss.seam.faces.environment.SeamApplicationWrapper
which looks like it will help me diagnose the underlying cause of the messages.
Can anyone tell me how to enable this logging level on a Glassfish server? I
could see nothing in the Seam 3 FAQ to help me.

Thanks.

I'm using Glassfish 3.1, JSF 2.1.3, Weld 1.1.1 & Seam 3.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert, but have you tried adding the line

> org.jboss.seam.faces.environment.SeamApplicationWrapper.level=DEBUG

to your domain's logging.properties file? It's in the config directory of your domain (e.g. [glassfish-install-directory]/glassfish/domains/domain1/config/logging.properties).